# Label Activate Load VBA

Tags: vba, events, label

I have been trying to do a simple code that makes my label bold when I call the userform from a buttom in the excel spread sheet.

```
Private Sub Label1_Load ()     
    Label1.Font.Bold = True    
end sub
```

However, Activate does not work, load, and Initialized did also not work. I am new in VBA, and I have been trying to find, and answer, but I have been not able to find one.

Comment: did you really try to do it within `Form initialize event`? it works for me when adding `Label1.Font.Bold = True` to `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`.

Comment: @KazJaw has already mentioned it how to do it but I have a question. Why are you trying to make the font bold via code? Why don't you set it at design time?

Comment: It is a very simple question, and actually I know that I can do it by pressing the three dots, and selecting bold. However, I might in the future just want to run a program when the macro is loaded which is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I do not know why, but Initialize is not working for me. May be, I am using it wrong. I select the label and added on the top of my userform. Then, I place the text I want, and double click in the label brings the default:

Private Sub Label1_Click

end sub

Comment: In this website, I realized that I can actually find the events on the tab. However, for some reason Initialized is not part of my library. Any idea how to add events in VBA
http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_form_initialize_event.html

Comment: To make things clear in my code window, I can only see:
BeforeDragOver,
BeforeDropOrPaste,
Click,
DbClick,
MouseUp,
MouseMove, and
MouseDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KazJaw and Siddharth Rout precised, Label1_Load () will never be triggered, as a label has no load() event. But a UserForm has a similar method Initialize():

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Label1.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

In VBA Excel. 
[image]

Comment: I do not have the load event in my procedure drop down list. How I add that?

Comment: my userform name was EmployeeData, and I was trying:

Private Sub EmpoyeeData_Initialize()
Label1.Font.Bold = True
End Sub

I did not know they have actually a default USERFORM name even if you changed it at the begining.

Comment: In effect, in a UserForm, the current form object is UserForm, in VBA Access Form, it's more simple, it's just Form. Enjoy the Bill GATES's good stuffs...